unable to Export scene created using perpective plotter in glb/gltf format
I want place the cube in the scene with the background image and export the complete scene in gltf format.
I tried with the below approach i am unable to export the image in the background
The following are the steps i followed:

Open blender with cube in the scene
Click on the Data tab, select the Background images click on the Open button to upload the image
In the Perspective Plotter option click on Match Background to align the cube to the scene
Now i tried to export the scene with image (Export ->gltf2.0 ->gltf Embedded (.gltf)) but the image is not getting exported



Most file formats don't include background images. Try placing the background image as a texture on a plane behind the cube instead.
